# Blazor Web App .NET 8: Line by line debugging is broken. Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, blazor-webassembly, .net-8.0

I just migrated my Blazor Web Assembly (.NET 7) app, to a Blazor Web App (Wasm) (.NET 8). Line by line debugging seems to be broken now. I can hit break-points, but as soon as i click F10 to step through my code, i get this error in Visual studio:

[image]

A new visual studio tab is then opened, that has the text "Unable to retrieve source content"

[image]

This is stopping me from doing line by line debugging in Blazor Web App (WASM). Restarting Visual Studio and my computer does not help.